# Timezone for server

Tags: python, django, timezone

I am building a application where the clients are supposed to pass a datetime field to query the database. But the client will be in different timezones, so how to solve that problem. 
Should I make it a point that the client's timezone is used as deafult for each user or the server for every user. And if so than how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

generally, the server is setup to run as UTC, which has no daylight saving time, etc, and each user's settings contains their preferred timezone. Then you do the time difference calculation. You DB might have that feature.

Comment: What do you mean my DB will have that feature? I am using MySQL, so where will that feature be?

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141611/handling-timezones-in-mysql-without-zoneinfo

Comment: @SaranshMohapatra See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1697304/php-mysql-timezone-clarification

Answer (score 0):

Just use the [django timezone](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/) feature to get the timezone of the user and to convert it to your local timezone for the db-query.